# Can't use Copy&Paste in Monodevelop on OSX 10.10

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I was working in a 2D game project on `OSX 10.10` with `Monodevelop`, but suddenly I couldn't use `Command + C` to Copy. Also, I could not use `Command + Z`, `+V` or `+A` or other edit hotkey.

However, I can select text and then right click to use copy and paste.

I have tried restarting `Unity`, `Monodevelop` and macbook, but it seems not to fix it. Has anyone encountered this problem and figured it out?

Comment: The Command+A issue has been around for a while, and they say it will be fixed in Unity 5.3. I don't have any other issues in Unity 5.2.

Comment: Really, I use 5.1.3, I will upgrade to 5.2 now!

Comment: I install 5.2, and it didn't appear the same problem, thanks!

Comment: Ah....it appear again, I should wait for 5.3....

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use monodevelop.
i am using VS CODE and it works perfectly fine with unity.
(i gave up on MD once it stopped copy pasting inside itself i could live with restarting MD in order to paste from chrome but inside the program??? hell no.)
just don't forget to install the c# and unity tools extensions

Comment: I've been a long time not to use `monodevelop`. I switch to sublime to develop.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a Bug .

But you can use main menu of `MonoDevelop` to solve this problem.

`Edit>Paste`   instead using `Ctrl+V` or `Command+V` 
.

Also `Build>Clean All`  and Restarting the `MonoDevelop` helped me !